# error al ingresar a las propiedades de un objeto

Tags: laravel, eloquent

tengo una consulta que me trae el alumno:

```
  $alumno = $this->alumnoRepository->buscarAlumnoPorIdConTipoAlumno(1);
```

cuerpo del método "buscarAlumnoPorIdConTipoAlumno":

```
 public function buscarAlumnoPorIdConTipoAlumno(int $idAlumno)
{
    return $this->model->with("tipoAlumno")->find($idAlumno);
}
```

el detalle esta cuando quiero imprimir los datos del tipo_alumno me aparece de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguna forma de solucionarlo,algo estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Difícil saberlo con sólo ese código. ¿Desde donde estás llamando al método del repositorio?¿desde un controlador?. ¿El repositorio está devolviendo los datos, pero los datos no se encuentran en la respuesta http?. ¿Podrías agregar el método completo donde se encuentra esta línea `$alumno = $this->alumnoRepository->buscarAlumnoPorIdConTipoAlumno(1);`?

Comment: ahi esta es el ultimo codigo